# GRPC send model from database

Tags: grpc

I created a model from the database table using `Scaffolding` in .NET Core 5.0:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=XXX;Database=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables SomeTable
```

**SomeTable.cs**

```
public partial class SomeTable
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; set; }
        public Guid? TypeUid { get; set; }
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateSent { get; set; }
        public bool IsSend { get; set; }
        public Guid? RefUid { get; set; }
    }
```

**some.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Test.Services";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

package some;

service SomeService {
  rpc GetSome (SomeRequest) returns (SomeReply);
}

message SomeRequest {
  int32 Count = 1;
}

message SomeToSent {
  string Uid = 1;
  google.protobuf.StringValue TypeUid = 2;
  google.protobuf.StringValueSender = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp DateSent = 4;
  bool IsSend = 5;
  google.protobuf.StringValue RefUid = 6;
  
}

message SomeReply {
  int32 Count = 1;
  repeated SomeToSent Some = 2;
}
```

But I don't know how to send it via `GRPC` clearly, because if I override rpc `GetSome`, then I need to send a repeated `SomeToSent` (and `Count`). But I don't want to map `SomeTable` to `SomeToSent`. I just want to send the list of `SomeTable` objects.

### Concrete question definition

How to properly send database objects via `GRPC` without mapping to proto models?

### P.S.

Yesterday, I created REST Api, which returns some of `SomeTable` rows in JSON format. Also, I made service, which returns these rows via GRPC. There're just about the same results if compare them by speed. But I spent more time on manual objects mapping. Every article which I was read told me that I must try to use GRPC instead of REST in case of CRUD in the REST. But I really don't see the difference. I drew a very approximate diagram of elapsed time (10000 rows):

[image]

This diagram based on debug info. And I still think that this mapping slows down the service response. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you **must** map between protos and your generated database table classes:

- gRPC can only transmit suitably-formatted objects over the network;
- the database expects suitably-formatted objects to persist|retrieve.

A benefit of this abstraction is that, if you change the database table schema, you need only revise the map rather than necessarily change the proto message and vice versa.

Another benefit is that, if you add different sources and sinks you your solution, you can consider using e.g. the proto messages as a universal format. You will then only need to write n+m mappings instead of n*m.

You may wish to consider a message that includes repeated `SomeToSent` messages and|or defining an `rpc` that streams messages.

Answer (score 0):

And if you persist only IMessages?, that way the client will do the unserialise and the server only sends the messages. For example a file like BoockMessage in git of Protobuffer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).